how to create change log of both new entity and modified entity simultaneously
Modifying table attributes is a frequent behavior, after modifying a bunch of tables in jdl file, including creating new tables and modifying old tables, I have to execute both following commands to create the delicate change log. I am not sure if it is the right way, or is there a effective way to do that? Thanks!
create modified entity change log
jhipster jdl .\road-parking.jdl  --incremental-changelog

create new entity change log
jhipster jdl .\road-parking.jdl

another way to create also involves two step command.
jhipster jdl .\road-parking.jdl --skip-db-changelog

./mvnw compile liquibase:diff

what my expecting way is just by only one command, thanks.
